# Warm start a conditional contextual bandit (Vowpal Wabbit)

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I am currently building a contextual bandit.
Since I neet to get the top 4 actions I am using the conditional contextual bandit in the Vowpal Wabbit framework.

I like to warm start my model but as far as I understand the framework, this is only possible with the classic contextual bandit.
Is there a way to warm start the ccb_explore_adf model for online learning?
What are the necessary commands and how does the dataformat for the training look like?

As I understand the ccb model that should also be (somehow) possible, since it is based on the cb model.